# Is it necessary to unset php password variable?

Tags: php, mysql, security

**Is it necessary to unset my password variable for my MySQL database.**

Currently, my code for my "dbpwd.php" is like this:

```
# database setup
$dbserver = "localhost";
$db_usrname = "blah";
$db_pwd = "blahblahblah";
$dbname = "blah";
```

but I was thinking.... is this a securtly concern.. because anyone can just do this:

```
 <?php
 include 'http://www.mywebsite.com/dbpwd.php';
 echo $db_usrname;
 echo $db_pwd;
 ?>
```

Wouldn't that give them full access to my stuff... so is it good practice to unset variables that are sensitive at the end of your php code? or is there something that I am missing?

---

Edit to clarify...

In this situation listed above... they would be using their own php server (not mine), and using include from there php file to get information from my server.

Comment: If someone has already uploaded their own script onto your server I think this is the least of your worries. They could just as easily email themselves a copy of the file containing the password.

Comment: @Lix I'm not sure the OP is aware that you cannot include another server's PHP files.

Comment: @Lix No the OP is asking about a remote include from someone else's server, if the script containing the db password is in a web-accessible location

Comment: Anyone who has access to your code? Does it matter what's happening on run-time if he already **has access**?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So you can't include something from someone else's server... all php includes must be local?

Comment: @Arian You could only include from someone else's server if the server was sending the code as plain text, and that would only happen if it was misconfigured or accessed via FTP or something -- not during a normal HTTP request.

Comment: @Arian You could _request_ the file, but the server would deliver its _output_, not its code.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski but when you include a php file, you receive all the set variables, right? so even though the code is hidden/executed, wouldn't it still be possible to echo variables?

Comment: @Arian But the "file" that gets included remotely doesn't look like the file stored on the server from the client's perspective.  Your web server doesn't send the variables, it only sends the output from the script (which is no output). Even though it comes from an `include` directive it is still _exactly_ the same as an HTTP request to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone attempts to perform a remote include via `allow_url_fopen` to your script, remember that from your server's point of view that is a regular HTTP request. A properly configured server would then *execute* the PHP code, rather than send it down as source.  So what they would receive, assuming your database configuration file produces no output, would be a blank document. They would not see or have access to your variables.

The result is the same as if you pointed your web browser to `http://www.mywebsite.com/dbpwd.php`.  You would see a blank page.

As I mentioned though, this relies on your web server being properly configured to execute PHP code (which it should be if your code runs when requested otherwise).  It is *always* recommended though, to place sensitive files outside the server's document root to avoid this issue should your server ever become *incorrectly* configured.

To answer the other part of your question, you do not need to unset any variables.  PHP will clean them up when they are no longer needed, and they are not a danger to your security.

Comment: What does it mean to have them outside the document root? Would it make sense to place my dbpwd.php outside the htdocs folder, so it wouldn't be online at all? only accessible by the localhost?

Comment: @Arian Yes, I assume your htdocs folder is probably your document root (in Apache, check the `DocumentRoot` directive). PHP can include a file from anywhere in the filesystem it has read access to - they don't have to be in the htdocs. So it is generally considered safest to store files above the document root. You might create an `includes/` directory that is at the same level as your `htdocs/` rather than inside `htdocs/`

Comment: In case it isn't clear - your web server will only accept requests for files that are inside the document root, which is the file location of `/` in  `http://example.com/`

Answer (score 0):

imho closing the database connection is quite enough and you do not need to unset those variables.

Also as Michael Berkowski pointed out - you need to put db connection files outside of document root.